# Is reduction possible from P to NP?

Tags: complexity-theory, computer-science, computation-theory, np

If X is poly-time reducible to Y, we can not say anything about X, even if Y is NP-hard, so there must exist some polytime solvable problems which can be reduced to some NP-hard problems.
Can someone provide some examples of it?

Answer (score 0):

The empty language is the only language which is many-one reducible to the empty language,

and the full language is the only language which is many-one reducible to the full language.

For all *other* languages Y, there is an element of Y and there is an element of Y's complement.

For all polytime solvable problems X, for all non-empty non-full languages Y,

for all elements y of Y, for all elements z of Y's complement,

```
solve the input
if the answer is yes:
    output y
else:
    output z
```

is a poly-time reduction from X to Y.